# Failed network error - When downloading a File

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I have this code to download files:

```
WebClient req = new WebClient();
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
string filePath = file.Path;
response.Clear();
response.ClearContent();
response.ClearHeaders();
response.Buffer = true;
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + _fileName + "\"");
response.ContentType = Path.GetExtension(filePath);

byte[] data = req.DownloadData(filePath);
response.BinaryWrite(data);
response.Flush();
response.Close();
```

Some of the variables like file.path and _fileName are from a list I created to save information from the upload control in asp.net webforms.

This download code works great on all browsers in my computer, but when I passed it to a local machine, it doesn't work at all, on firefox it downloads but I can't open the file, and on chrome it says Failed Network Error.

The files are uploaded on my C: drive, but on the machine they are uploaded on a fileshare that simulates a C: drive. I used logs to understand if he was getting the file properly, and this is what I get:

```
\\10.50.237.18\opt\Liferay_DATA\eforms\20180126\70edd349-8cd1-4518-a55e-d49dcadb3f7c\0eadc797-7817-4e99-b39a-35f179ec1c5d.pdf
```

For What I understood, the file is being upload properly. But when I'm trying to download it, it's not working. I know this is a common question, but I check several solutions and I can't seem to make it work. Could you please help me understand what the problem is? Maybe the response.header?

Comment: Does _10.50.237.18_ is the machine that store the uploaded files and the machine that try to download the files?

Comment: @KernelMode They are different. The machine that uploads the files is one thing and sends all files to 10.50.237.18.  Maybe I should use WebClient.DownloadFile(ulrfrommachine, filename)?

Comment: So the files are stores in _10.50.237.18_. And the machine that tries to download is a different machine?

Comment: @KernelMode Thats exactly it.

Comment: I see. So what happens when you try to download (with same .NET object and the same file) using simple command in PowerShell? `$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient \n
$WebClient.DownloadFile(fileUriToDownlaod,outputFile)` 
What is the error you get?

Comment: I just want to eliminate the option of no access or permissions (Run it from the machine that tries to download. Not from 10.50.237.18)

Comment: @KernelMode The machine that uploads files doesn't have powershell, I can't test it.  But I can try on my machine. Give me a moment.

Comment: @KernelMode Sorry, for taking so long, Since the machine doesn't have powershell, and you said in the comment that it should be the machine that tries to download, but I tried on my computer  and I ran the command and said "The network path was not found". Maybe I did something wrong in the command. But according to logs, the path does exists and it uploads there.